# Undefined operator error when using specialised template

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I am using the latest version of MSVC with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, and I am having some issues with template specialisation and operator overloading.

I have the following (header only) vector class snippet. I have excluded unnecessary code (i.e. identical specialisations for vec2 and vec4).

```
template <typename T, int n>
struct VectorN
{
    T data[n];

    T& operator[](const int i);
};

template <typename T, int n>
T& VectorN<T, n>::operator[](const int i)
{
    static_assert(i >= 0 && i < n, "Index out of range");
    return data[i];
}

template <typename T, int n>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const VectorN<T, n>& vec)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        os << vec[i];
    }
    return os;
}
```

With the following specialisation:

```
template <typename T>
struct VectorN<T, 3>
{
    union
    {
        T data[3];

        struct
        {
            T x, y, z;
        };
    };
};

typedef VectorN<int, 3> Vec3i;
typedef VectorN<float, 3> Vec3f;
```

The main function that I am compiling is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Vec3f vec{ 0, 1, 2 };

    std::cout << vec << std::endl;

    char dump;
    std::cin >> dump;
    std::cin.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect that it works, however, I get an `Error: C2676 binary '[': 'const VectorN<float,3>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator`

I believe that the ostream operator is working as intended, but that the indexing operator is not. Is there anything that I am doing that is obviously wrong, or does the current MSVC simply not support what I am trying to do?

Comment: The specialization doesn't have access to the members of its base template. You can create a common base class from which to inherit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the `union`-based solution to access a 3-dimensional vector with both `data` and `x`, `y`, `z`, you can use [CTRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to create a base class which is aware of the derived classes' `data` member:

```
namespace impl
{
    template <typename T, int n, typename TDerived>
    struct VectorBase
    {
        const T& operator[](const int i) const
        {   
            assert(i >= 0 && i < n);
            return static_cast<const TDerived&>(*this).data[i];
        }
    };
}
```

Your derived classes can then be implemented as follows:

```
template <typename T, int n>
struct VectorN : impl::VectorBase<T, n, VectorN<T, n>>
{
    T data[n];
};

template <typename T>
struct VectorN<T, 3> : impl::VectorBase<T, 3, VectorN<T, 3>>
{
    union
    {
        T data[3];

        struct
        {
            T x, y, z;
        };
    };

    VectorN(T ax, T ay, T az) : data{ax, ay, az} {}
};
```

A [working example is available on wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/O8t8y6ATL2RUR0b1).

Comment: Thank you! This looks fantastic. It also looks like there is no run time cost? I will give you a tick when I've got a minute to test this.

Comment: Great, works perfectly! Thanks for explaining a solution that still maintains what I wanted to do :)

Comment: Ah @Vittorio-Romeo , this is missing one thing that I can't quite figure out, however. How do I enable a non-const reference return? I would like the value to be modifiable, but if I do that then I again run into issues.
Firstly, removing the const complains about `cannot convert from 'const float' to 'float &'`, and Secondly if I remove the const from the static_cast, I have the same issue as in the original post...

Comment: Apologies for the long chain, but I solved that new issue by simply having a const and a non-const version of the operator. In case anyone sees this in the future and is wondering ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `operator<<` **works** because you have an appropriate overloading for your `VectorN` templated type.

From the other side, `operator[]` **does not work**, because there is no `operator[]` in the specialized version of `VectorN` (and compiler kindly tell you about it).

You can either add `operator[]` to the specialized version of `VectorN` class or, as @DeiDei mentioned, try to move some functionality to the base class.